# Rspec mocks and stubs confuse with expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have confuse when use mocks and stubs in rspec on rails. I have test like below

```
require 'rails_helper'

class Payment
  attr_accessor :total_cents

  def initialize(payment_gateway, logger)
    @payment_gateway = payment_gateway
    @logger = logger
  end

  def save
    response = @payment_gateway.charge(total_cents)
    @logger.record_payment(response[:payment_id])
  end
end

class PaymentGateway
  def charge(total_cents)
    puts "THIS HITS THE PRODUCTION API AND ALTERS PRODUCTION DATA. THAT'S BAD!"

    { payment_id: rand(1000) }
  end
end

class LoggerA
  def record_payment(payment_id)
    puts "Payment id: #{payment_id}"
  end
end

describe Payment do
  it 'records the payment' do
    payment_gateway = double()
    allow(payment_gateway).to receive(:charge).and_return(payment_id: 1234)
    logger = double('LoggerA')
    expect(logger).to receive(:record_payment).with(1234)
    payment = Payment.new(payment_gateway, logger)
    payment.total_cents = 1800
    payment.save
  end
end
```

Ok when I run rspec it works, no problem, but when I try to move `expect` to last line like below:

```
    payment = Payment.new(payment_gateway, logger)
    payment.total_cents = 1800
    payment.save

    expect(logger).to receive(:record_payment).with(1234)
```

and I try to run rpsec, it fail, I dont know why expect is last line will fail, I thought that expect always puts in last line before we run something to get result to test. Anyone can explain for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expect(sth).to receive` sets a message expectation which is to be satisfied between the call and end of the test, and that expectation is verified after the test finishes. When you move the `expect` to the last line, expectation is set just at the end of the test and no code is executed to satisfy it so it fails. Unfortunately it means breaking the prepare-execute-test order.

Which is why you should really rarely use `expect.to receive` and replace it with `allow.to receive` with `expect.to have_received`

```
# prepare
allow(logger).to receive(:record_payment)

# execute 
..

# test
expect(logger).to have_received(:record_payment).with(1234)
```

`allow.to receive` sets up a mock proxy which starts tracing received messages which then can be explicitly verified by `expect.to have_received`. Some objects automatically sets their mock proxies, for example you don't need `allow.to receive` for doubles with predefined responses or `spies`. In your case, you could write the test like:

```
payment_gateway = double
allow(payment_gateway).to receive(:charge).and_return(payment_id: 1234)
logger = double('LoggerA', record_payment: nil)
payment = Payment.new(payment_gateway, logger)
payment.total_cents = 1800
payment.save

expect(logger).to have_received(:record_payment).with(1234)
```

### Other notes

I strongly recommend using verifiable_doubles, which will protect you from false positives:

```
payment_gateway = instance_double(PaymentGateway)
allow(payment_gateway).to receive(:charge).and_return(payment_id: 1234)
```

This test will now raise an exception if there is no `charge` method defined on PaymentGateway class - protecting you from your tests passing even in case you rename that method but forgot to rename it in the test and implementation.

Comment: Thank for your explain, I got it.